# Passing data from view to controller (Zend)

Tags: php, zend-framework

I basically need to be able to pass through a $q that is a
variable of a search form to a controller, which then calls an api and does
a search with that $q..(it can be a an ID,ISBN or a title of the book).

http://pastebin.com/zMZxnJ81   this is my view

http://pastebin.com/JQ3HmFA9   this is my controller

I cannot pass the data from the view to the controller, I get the "last condition" message of the if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form method attribute can be set to "get" or "post". "request" which is the one you set, is not a valid value for method attribute.

You can have a look at your php.ini for $_REQUEST super global array settings like request_order setting.

Also it's a better way to use Zend request object functions such as

```
$this->_request->getParams()
$this->_request->getParam($key)
```

Comment: Or, directly, in the controller, `$this->_getAllParams()` or `$this->_getParam('q', 'some default value')`, which work the same way as the above answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with `$this->getRequest()->getParam('q')` instead of using `$_REQUEST`?